# Minimizing a variable in a non-linear system of equations

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, nonlinear-system

I am having trouble with the following problem:

[image: A geometric representation of the problem]

There are these points $A = (x_A, y_A)$ and $B = (x_B, y_B)$. $A$ is connected to $C$ by a rigid bar of length $L$ and a similar bar connects $B$ to $D$. A third bar, of length $d$, connects C to D. I need to find, for given $A$ and $B$, the position of $G = (x_G,y_G)$, which is the middle point of $\overline{CD}$, that minimizes $y_G$ (the vertical position of $G$), as well as the angle $\theta$ between $\overline{CD}$ and the horizontal axis.

I was able to establish the following system of equations:

$$(x_C - x_A)^2 + (y_C - y_A)^2 - L^2 = 0$$

$$(x_D - x_B)^2 + (y_D - y_B)^2 - L^2 = 0$$

$$(x_C - x_D)^2 + (y_C - y_D)^2 - d^2 = 0$$

$$y_G = \frac{y_C + y_D}{2}$$

With the above system in hands, I am able to find the minimal value for $y_G$ and then calculate $x_G$ and $\theta$, right? But how do I do it?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Do you know something about optimization? Which things?

Comment: There is a missing equation for A between B

Comment: Well, I know that I have to take the derivative of yG and equal it to 0.

Comment: you need to introduce $\theta$ in terms of $x_C , x_D, y_C, y_D$ then using some trigonomical relations you'll be able to find the optimal solution. $ d\theta = 0$

Comment: Do you know Karush Kuhn Tucker?

Comment: my plan was to find the minimal $y_G$, and only then find $x_C$ and $\theta$

Comment: I think with angles is easier...

Comment: I have never heard of Karush Kuhn Tucker before

Comment: well, I have $y_G = \frac{y_A - \sqrt{(L^2 - (x_C - x_A)^2)} + y_B - \sqrt{(L^2 - (x_D - x_B)^2)}}{2}$. in respect to what do I have to derivate this expression?